# A set of points and vector field

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a set of points which display the velocity vectors on some coordinates of space. I want to have the vector field plot which visualize my datasets. Can you tell me how can I do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's 2 dimensional measurements, you can start by plotting a dot at each coordinate you measured, with "scatter(x,y)". As we'll see soon, you won't be using your first and last measurement, so it should be:

```
scatter(x(2:end-1), y(2:end-1))
```

Next, you'll need the direction of each vector. If your measruements frequency is high enough, numerical derivative should give you the right results. "diff(vec)" will return a vector of the differences between adjacent points. so you can get right side derivative of each point by:

```
dy = diff(y)
dx = diff(x)
% to be able to differentiate even when dx=0, will replace 0 with a very small number
for i=(dx == 0)
    dx(i) = eps
der = dy/dx
```

However, you'll probably need the "average" derivative, which you can obtain by:

```
avg_der = (der(1:end-1) + der(2:end)) / 2
```

now, you can draw a line at each point you've drawn, with dx=dx/normalization_size, dy=der * dx / normalization_size. Lines can be plotted.

```
for i=1:length(avg_der)
    line([x(i+1) (x(i+1) + mean(dx(i:i+1))/NORMALIZATION)], [y(i+1) (y(i+1) + avg_der(i) * mean(dx(i:i+1))/NORMALIZATION)])
```